# Find elements missing from an array of ordered numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `array` of numbers ordered. I define a number `e` to be *missing* from `array` if:

- For some element `v` of `array`, `e` is either `v + 1` or `v - 1`,
- `e` is not an element of `array`, and
- `e` is not smaller than `0`.

For example, the elements missing from:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]
```

are:

```
[3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18]
```

How can I find the elements missing from a given array `array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want something like:

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]
possible_missing = array.flat_map {|e| [e-1, e+1]}.uniq
#=> [1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 11, 13, 12, 14, 16, 18]
diff = (possible_missing - array).select {|e| e >= 0}
#=> [3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Consider using `- [-1]` instead of heavy `O(N)` `select >= 0`. Also, `[e-1, e+1]` is sufficiently enough inside `flat_map`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, i argee with `[e-1, e+1]`. About index instead select - what about case if array first element not `0`?

Comment: Excuse me? The only superfluous element that might appear in the resulting array, is `-1`. That said, `- [-1]` and `select { |e| e >= 0 }` are _an exact equivalent_: `arr.flat_map { |e| (e - 1..e + 1).to_a }.uniq - arr - [-1]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, oh, sorry, did not understand your idea first time. You are right, but I think we can find only possible missing elements like in edited answer, without  `(e - 1..e + 1).to_a`

Comment: Yes, sure, I just copy-pasted the code I played with here. Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I don't follow your point. If the first element of `array` were `-7` your suggestion would result in the first element of `diff` being `-8`. No?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, element in original array is not smaller than 0

Comment: We are given an ordered array of numbers. Nowhere does it say they are natural numbers (i.e., non-negative). No? Am I missing something? The example has no negative numbers, but nothing can be drawn from that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland third condition in OP states: “e is not smaller than 0.” `select { |e| e >= arr.first }` might make sense for general case.

Comment: @mudasobwa, that condition only pertains to "missing numbers", not to the numbers in the array. For example, the array might be `[-7, -1, 0, 4]`, in which case the missing numbers would be `[1, 3, 5]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh, you are right, strictly speaking the input might contain negatives. I misread the original conditions.

Comment: @mudasobwa no in the original question I said the smallest element is 0. No idea why it was changed to current statement. The current statement is not what I meant.

Comment: @mudasobwa, you are not losing your mind. You posted your comment before sawa edited out the statement that the smallest value of the array is zero. (Actually, I don't know if you you're losing your mind or not, but there is no evidence here that you are.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I occasionally am, but not in this particular case :)

Comment: @newguy Without the condition on the output, the output should include `-1` (coming from `0`), contrary to the given example. That is why I put the condition on the output. If there should also be the same condition on the input array, then the OP should have written so. The OP didn't mention that point. It is the OP's fault.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this would probably be with [inject.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) This allows you to build a new array in only one pass. It's not particularly rubyish because you'll need to write the algorithm. Instead of relying on build in functions. But it is probably the most efficient way of doing it.

The following algorithm ends each iteration with the final value of the returned array being n+1 where n is the last item evaluated. If the next item would exclude that item it replaces it with n+1. If the next item is more than 2 greater than the previous, it also inserts n-1.

```
present = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]

present.inject([]) {|absent,n| 
    # If a number has been skipped at n -1 and n +1
    if (absent.empty? or absent.last < n - 1) && n > 0
       absent << n -1 << n + 1

    # if n-1 is already present or the new array is still empty, add n+1
    elsif absent.empty? or absent.last == n-1 
      absent << n + 1

    # if the last element of the absent list should be excluded because it is n, replace it with n+1
    elsif  absent.last == n
      # replace last absent with next
      absent[absent.length-1] = n + 1 
      absent

    # in all other cases do nothing
    else absent
    end
}

# => [3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]

b = ([arr[0]-1,0].max..arr[-1]+1).to_a - arr
  #=> [3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18] 
(b - b.each_cons(3).with_object([]) { |(c,d,e),f| f << d if e==c+2 })
  #=> [3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]
range = (0..(array.max + 1))
(range.to_a - array).select do |el| 
  [el-1, el+1].any?{|el2| array.include?(el2)}
end
# => [3, 7, 8, 11, 14, 16, 18]
```