# How can I find the missing letter in an array

Tags: ruby

Given an array of letters `arr = ["a","b","c","d","f"]`, I would like to construct an array containing all letters between the smallest and largest letters (by ASCII value) in `arr` that are not contained in `arr`. Here that would be `["e"]`. How can I to that?

Comment: Define "missing letter".

Comment: Seems similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043122/find-elements-missing-from-an-array-of-ordered-numbers

Comment: I voted to reopen, not realizing that my vote would do that very thing. This question differs from the [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043122/find-elements-missing-from-an-array-of-ordered-numbers) in two respects: the earlier question had an additional requirement (that "missing" elements be non-negative) and here the number of elements missing is said to be one, rather than (as in the earlier question) any number (including zero).  My answer, for example, would not be appropriate for the earlier question.

Comment: GabeA, I may have changed your question with my edit. The title suggests it is known there is exactly one "missing" value, but my edit allows there to be any number. If I got that wrong, please edit to correct (and accept my apologies).

Answer (score 4):

```
a = %w[a b c d f]

(a.min..a.max).to_a - a # => ["e"]
```

Comment: It's a shame that `minmax` isn't a good fit here: `Range.new(*a.minmax)` seems awfully messy.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the letters in the array are within "a" to "z" and ordered alphabetically, you could fetch the array's [`first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-first) and [`last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-last) element:

```
given_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"]

first_letter = given_letters.first #=> "a"
last_letter  = given_letters.last  #=> "f"
```

and call [`String#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-upto) and [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) to retrieve an array of all successive letters:

```
all_letters = first_letter.upto(last_letter).to_a
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

which can be used to calculate the difference to the original array via [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-2D):

```
all_letters - given_letters
#=> ["e"]
```

Comment: Perhaps use `given_letters.minmax`.

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
ascii = arr.uniq.map(&:ord)
  #=> [97, 98, 99, 100, 102]
sm, lg = ascii.minmax
   #=> [97, 102]
```

If it is known that there is exactly one letter `e` for which `sm < e.ord < lg` and `e` is not an element of `arr`, we can write the following.

```
((sm+lg)*(lg-sm+1)/2 - ascii.sum).chr
  #=> (597 - 496).chr => 101.chr => "e"
```

That is because `sm..lg` represents an arithmetic progression; hence, the sum of its elements equals

```
(sm+lg)*(lg-sm+1)/2
  #=> 597
```

Comment: Interesting solution, although your edit of the question implies that there could be more than one letter: _"all letters [...] not contained in arr"_